# Turning on Compiler Optimization causing an exception

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I've got a C# Web project that uses interop.domino.dll which uses COM to interact with a lotus notes database.

Everything works fine when deploying the application in debug mode. However, when optimization is enabled in release mode, I'm getting a System.AccessViolationException.

This is the exception:

> " System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
> protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
> corrupt"

I only see the error when optimization is turned on for release mode.

This only happens when multiple threads are used to read all the items from a view in lotus notes. Is it possible that the compiler optimization is causing this issue?

Comment: Crashes due to threading race bugs are *very* timing-sensitive.  A minor change in code executing order or speed can reveal them.  You are very, very lucky that it happens now instead of once a month in production.

Comment: So is it unlikely that the compiler optimization is causing the issue? I read somewhere that compiler optimization can cause issues when using unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes internals are highly dependent on shared memory, and the COM APIs that are exposed through the Interop DLL are not necessarily thread-safe. In fact, I have a dim memory from somewhere at least 10 years ago that view operations are definitely not thread-safe so the recommended way of writing multi-threaded code would be to have a single thread responsible for reading the view to get a list of all the noteids or unids, and then dispatching threads to read the documents. If the document handler threads don't delete or alter documents in any way that would affect the view sorting, it might still be safe to overlap the single thread that's processing the view with the threads that are handling the documents, and that might gain some performance, but in most cases I think it's probably not going to be worth it.